# using a button to go to another xml file in android

Tags: android, xml

i have a class called `TapCounter` which is in a `tap_counter.xml` file. and another `xml` file which is showing the main screen. in the main screen i have a start button. using the start button, i want it to direct the user to the `tapCounter` screen. is it possible? do i have to put anything in the `tapCounter` screen?

```
public class TapCounter extends Activity {

    //keep track of the count
    private int mCount = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tap_counter);

         final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.pressed1);
         final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.pressed2);
         final MediaPlayer mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.pressed3);

        final TextView countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCount);
         ImageButton countButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlus);
         ImageButton decreaseButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ButtonMinus);
         ImageButton resetButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ButtonReset);


        countButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp1.start();
                mCount++;
                if (mCount < 0) {
                    countTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                }
                else  {

                    countTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                }
                countTextView.setText(""+mCount+"");
                }
        });

        decreaseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp2.start();
                mCount--;

                if (mCount < 0) {
                    countTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                }
                else  {

                    countTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                }
                countTextView.setText(""+mCount+"");
            }
        });


    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp3.start();
            mCount=0;
            if (mCount < 0) {
                countTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            }
            else  {

                countTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            }
            countTextView.setText(""+mCount+"");
        }
    });



        }

}
```

Comment: just to be clear, you want to go to previous screen OR main screen/activity on click of a button??

Comment: please R&D on internet before post questions here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your main screen start TapCounter activity using an intent.

Answer (score 0):

In the Main Activity add this lines of code

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,TapCounterActivity.class));

            }
        });
```

Comment: actually i have made two class which corresponds to two xml file each.. its basically a similar thing but different theme style app. i have also a setting.xml file which allows the user to choose either one of the theme. so when a user choose a particular theme, the radio button in the setting.xml will save it and open that theme, and not the other one.

Comment: so where shud i declare the radiobutton and in where? the themes? or my main menu?